# Browser is giving "200 stream not found netstream.play.streamnotfound clip" error what is the error in the code

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have write a code to fetch the video from the server folder and play it on web page. i am using flowplayer.it shows the video player with controls but not playing the video.what could be the problem . code is attached

**Code in aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebsiteTaskAsp.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 73px">

        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblFilename" runat="server" Text="File Name :"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUploadMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="videoNameTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload" /><br /><br />


    </div>
        <div>
<hr />
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" Visible="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    RepeatColumns="2" CellSpacing="5">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <u>
            <%# Eval("vname") %></u>
        <hr />
        <a class="player" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block" href='<%# Eval("vpath") %>'>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<script src="FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    flowplayer("a.player", "FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
        plugins: {
            pseudo: { url: "FlowPlayer/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.12.swf" }
        },
        clip: { provider: 'pseudo', autoPlay: false },
    });
</script>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


**Code in aspx.cs**



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebsiteTaskAsp
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Khawaja\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TaskDB;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Khawaja\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TaskDB;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from videos";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataList1.DataBind();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//UploadedVideos//"+str);
                string path = "~//UploadedVideos//"+str.ToString();
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO videos VALUES('"+videoNameTextbox.Text+"','"+path+"')",con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                lblUploadMsg.Text = "Video Uploaded Successfully";
            }
        }
    }
}
```